# Create Windows installation media in a disk partition of internal second hard drive. (like bootable usb with rufus)

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning, bootable-media, recovery

I have windows 10 installed in a SSD and my laptop has another internal HDD. I frequently mess up windows trying new thing. So, i always need a Windows installation media available (created a bootable usb for that purpose). Now I am thinking if I can use a internal partition of the second hard drive as Windows installation media. So that if necessary, I can change the boot order to boot from HDD and repair/install windows on SSD. After installation, I could just simply change the boot order back to SSD. That would be super convenient as my recovery media would be built right into the laptop. I will be grateful if you help me.

Answer (score 0):

The description you provided is the way older systems used to be managed.  Windows 10 is very different. Most especially, it is a new system each 6 - 9 months.

Unless you are screwing up more frequently than every 6 months, you can easily get the current Windows 10 ISO from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Normal problems can be fixed first with DISM and then Windows Repair Install if DISM does not work. This is easier that reinstalling Windows.

Use Windows 10 Sandbox for trying new things. Windows Sandbox is a temporary virtual machine and is part of Windows 10 Pro newest versions.

If you have Windows 10 Home, use VMware Player or Virtual Box to make "disposable" machines.

This is much easier than reinstalling Windows every time you have an error

Comment: Actually, i don't update windows regularly. (i might do a clean install of latest windows every two year.) And i don't have access to other PC nor do I have good internet connection. From your first line, it is evident that what i want is not impossible. Can you give me the direction to accomplish this? And Thank you for taking your time replying me.

Comment: You can put the Windows ISO on your drive in known location and run it when you need to (a) Repair, or (b) Reinstall. It is very easy with Windows 10. Just make a folder for this.

Comment: what if i can't boot? how would i run that file?

Comment: Yes you can run that file. However, if Windows is not running, you cannot run a repair, you can only run it and use the option to retain data and reinstall Windows. I mentioned in my answer that you should consider Windows Sandbox to run things that might break your computer. Also, be sure (beyond certain) that your data is fully backed up. You can keep the Windows ISO folder on a USB hard drive or large USB Key.

Comment: okay. i got what you trying to say, But can you give me brief hint how can i accomplish what i asked about. All I want is  bootable full recovery media available even if i delete the entire C drive.

Comment: You can use Rufus or other to make the Windows ISO into a bootable media.  See if the Media Creation Link will make the ISO bootable. You can do this and make a USB Key to start with. You need to renew this process each 6 - 9 months.

Comment: Yes, i can make bootable pendrive from windows ISO by rufus. But can I do the same with internal disk partition (from second hard drive) instead of pendrive?

Comment: Only if the machine will start. You asked about it not running. You can make the folder on your hard drive, start with a Windows boot disk and run Setup in that folder.

Comment: Okay. got it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Considering your situation, I think you can use a clone tool like aomei, acronis, easeus or whatever to create a full copy of the boot drive (or the operation system only) to your HDD.

The cloned drive is bootable as long as it meets some conditions, e.g. it should have enough space for cloning, and the partition style should be the same with your SSD...

You can check this one as a reference: [clone windows to hdd or ssd](https://www.ubackup.com/clone/clone-os-to-ssd-lenovo-6988.html)

Comment: That's a nice idea. I will try next time i do a clean install. But with a recovery media i could repair existing windows